You can't solve this one
Preface
A... business associate of mine sent me this message. I can't decipher it, but I know it's important! Can you help me?
I know the message contains two components; a message, and a safehouse codename. The message tells me what's happened, and the codename tells me which safehouse I need to go to.
To keep their locations secret, we've give our safehouses codenames which are five letter English words.
So, to get all the content of the message (and to solve the puzzle!) you'll need to tell me:

The text (or at least the intent) of the message.
The codename of the safehouse I need to get to!

Good luck!
Message

"Frajer assem rašuk; ket ostlay."

Clues

 The title is a big clue.


 You shouldn't need any cryptography knowledge for this one.


 The theme/flavour of the puzzle is somewhat related to the solution.


 This is a knowledge puzzle; knowledge gathering tools will help you, more than you think.


Sounds like your message has come from Harry in Home Alone! ;-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_c5aLUh8eI

@Stiv Heh heh :P

Should "ostlay" be "osztaly"?

@DanielS Sadly not!

Partial solution:

  I think these are uncommon or dead languages?

Frajer

  This appears to be Croatian or Czech for "Dude"

assem

  I think this is Latin for "as"

rašuk

  Looking this up on Google shows that it means "man" in Adurgari

ket

No clue on what this one is

ostlay

 I think this is Pig Latin for "lost" but I'm not entirely sure

So I'm not entirely sure on the message, but the safeword could be

 CLASP or CLAMP, found by taking the first letters of each languages


You're very close to the idea! You've got a couple right. You're not a million miles away from a full solution here.

Thought about it some more and still can't seem to get anywhere, which ones do I have right?

rot13(Lbhe nffrffzrag bs gur chmmyr vf pybfr gb gur gehgu, ohg fyvtugyl vanpphengr. Lbh unir enfhx naq bfgynl pbeerpg. Guvax nobhg gur chmmyr'f gurzvat.)
